# Jquery grow/shrink Div onclick

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I was wondering how to achieve the effect found at : http://thekitchencommunity.com/
in the what's happening in the kitchen section (lower-left). Can someone suggest a similar logic?

It's pretty nice I must say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CUJSM/3/

Here is an EXACT example of what is happening there.... It's not styled that wonderful, so use your imagination.

Comment: Not a problem. If you want to have an arrow that changes from a downward arrow to an upward arrow, you will just need to add an if statement to that function as well. It will just add a class and remove a class from that whatever DIV the arrow is located in. I can edit that JSFiddle and re-link it if that is what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uP8Tj/

Use the slideUp and slideDown methods in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

They are moving the div offset to a negative value relative to the bottom of the screen.  If you try scrolling on the the before it is up, you will notice that you can drag it down.

The way that I've done this before is to use the jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) effect.  It's also fun to try changing the opacity while it moves!

But regardless, swap out the image of the arrow on click and animate the containing div from a negative value relative to the bottom to zero.